# A problem when downloading accimage library

Tags: visual-studio

I got a problem when l try to download accimage.

when i run in Powershell to download accimage,it's got an error.

```
PS E:\Working and Learning\biancheng\cnnimageretrieval-pytorch-master\accimage-master> python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'accimage' extension
F:\App\VS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:/jpeg-turbo64/include -IC:/Users/KAI/opt/intel/ipp/include -IE:\Anaconda\include -IE:\Anaconda\include -IF:\App\VS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IF:\App\VS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include -IF:\App\VS\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcaccimagemodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\accimagemodule.obj
accimagemodule.c
F:\App\VS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:/jpeg-turbo64/include -IC:/Users/KAI/opt/intel/ipp/include -IE:\Anaconda\include -IE:\Anaconda\include -IF:\App\VS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include -IF:\App\VS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include -IF:\App\VS\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcjpegloader.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\jpegloader.obj
jpegloader.c
jpegloader.c(5): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件: “jpeglib.h”: No such file or directory
error: command 'F:\\App\\VS\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
PS E:\Working and Learning\biancheng\cnnimageretrieval-pytorch-master\accimage-master>
```

The Path of "jpeglib.h" is included

"setup.py"

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

accimage = Extension(
    "accimage",
    include_dirs=["C:/jpeg-turbo64/include", "C:/Users/KAI/opt/intel/ipp/include"],
    libraries=["jpeg", "ippi", "ipps"],
    library_dirs=["C:/jpeg-turbo-gcc64/lib", "C:/Users/KAI/opt/intel/ipp/Lib"],
    sources=["accimagemodule.c", "jpegloader.c", "imageops.c"],
)

setup(
    name="accimage",
    version="0.2.0",
    description="Accelerated image loader and preprocessor for Torch",
    author="Marat Dukhan",
    author_email="maratek@gmail.com",
    ext_modules=[accimage],
)
```

I tried some solutions but it didn't work.I dont't know why it would happend.

Comment: Post code and error messages as text.

Comment: I have post some code and file.if there is anything needed,just tell me.thanks.

Comment: You updated the includePath which is the correct action for the first problem.   Not sure what the issue is for the 2nd problem but I added the visual-studio tag as it's not really a c problem at this point.  Also, please revise your question so it's one problem (Go to Document).  The powershell issue is that you probably need to specify the include path that you added in the includePath.  I don't know what the argument is for your compiler.  Please revise question so it's 1 problem only, remove the images which just add noise.  Good job on the first update.

Comment: thank you, I have solved the problem.I revised "library_dirs" of the "setup.py",I found that the file path was not set correctly.All problems have been solved.Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please  write up an answer so others can benefit from what you learned.

Answer (score 0):

Before downloading the accimage,you need to download ipp(Intel Integrated Performance Primitives) and jepg-turbo first.You need to pay attention to downloading the corresponding jpeg-turbo for your compiler.
After that,make sure that the Path of the two library in "setup.py" is correct.So that you can run it successfully.

Comment: What I'm going to say next might be a bit silly,but accimage is used on linux not windows.